# Find the modulus and the principal argument of $-2i$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let,
$z=0+(-2i)$

$\therefore$ mod of $z=2$

But, I am getting stuck over here and I am unable to find the argument as the $\tan\alpha$ comes out to be not defined.

Any hint or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than just approaching it with a formula think about it graphically. Where is $-2i$ located on an Argand diagram?

It is on the vertical axis below the origin. Thus the argument is $-\frac{\pi}{2}$.

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain me that? Thanks for the help though!

Comment: This is very good advice.

Comment: @Abhishekstudent I've added a diagram. If that doesn't help please state what you mean by "Can you please explain me that?" I did explain it.

Comment: Thanks sir for your priceless time. I am really grateful to you.